# linq group by and select inside group by gives error EFcore

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I have a class

```
 public class statisticsDaily
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<float> Production { get; set; }
        public Nullable<float> m_wind_speed { get; set; }
        public Nullable<float> Availability { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public string TurbineId { get; set; }
        public string Countries { get; set; }
        
    }
```

i need to apply the aggregate function on some field and also select the rest of the fields from my class

```
var rslt = await (from d in db.statMonth.Include(f=>f.MasterData).Where(d=>d.m_turbine_id == IPAddress.Parse(id) && d.m_date >= frm)
                      group d by new { d.m_date.Month, d.m_date.Year} into g 
                      select new statisticsDaily
                      {
                          Year = g.Key.Year// We can access Year now since we grouped by Year as well
                          Date = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(g.Key.Month),
                          Production = g.Sum(s => s.m_energy_prod),
                          m_wind_speed = g.Average(s => s.m_wind_speed),
                          Availability = g.Average(s => s.m_availability),
                          Comments=g.Select(s=>s.Comments).ToString(),
                          Countries=g.select(i=>i.Country).ToString()              
                      }
         ).OrderBy(s=>s.Date).ToListAsync();
```

it gives me error :
The LINQ expression 'Select<v_stats_daily, string>(
source: GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: CAST(DATE_PART('month', v.m_date)) AS integer),
ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression:
EntityType: v_stats_daily
ValueBufferExpression:
ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
IsNullable: False
,
selector: (i) => i.m_comment)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

Comment: What is an "*error 500*"? Have you tried debugging the code and see if there is an exception?

Comment: And how does that even compile? You have multiple errors in your code. `Year` is not defined on `statisticsDaily`,  you are missing a `,` after the assingment. `Comments=g.Select(i=>s.Comments).ToString()` uses two different variable names

Comment: @derpirscher edited,when it wants to run the linq,it skips from it

Comment: What do you mean by *it skips from it*. Have you tried to debug that particular piece of code and check if there is an exception thrown?

Comment: @derpirscher updated by the error,got it with try and catch

Comment: Furthermore `g.Select(s=>s.Comments).ToString()` is probably not doing, what you expect it to do, but will result in your Comments to be something like `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Program+data,System.String]`

Comment: I'm not very familiary with EF so I can't really help there, but have you tried the solutions proposed in the error message?

Comment: It seems likely that the call `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(g.Key.Month),` cannot be translated to a SQL statement. You should just bring back the `g.Key.Month` and then convert after the query after using an `AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: i removed the Cilture part but still error,when should i add asEnumerable? @Enigmativity

Comment: @mortezasol - What's the `IPAddress.Parse(id)` bit doing in there?

Comment: @mortezasol - It's starting to look like fake code. What's `g.select(i=>i.Country)` doing? Can you post real code? A [mcve] would be great.

Comment: Even `g.Select(s=>s.Comments).ToString()` is fake.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the closest that I could come to fixing your query.

```
var rslt =
(
    await
    (
        from d in db.statMonth.Include(f => f.MasterData)
        where d.m_turbine_id == IPAddress.Parse(id)
        where d.m_date >= frm
        group d by new { d.m_date.Month, d.m_date.Year } into g
        orderby g.Key.Month
        select new
        {
            Year = g.Key.Year,
            Date = g.Key.Month,
            Production = g.Sum(s => s.m_energy_prod),
            m_wind_speed = g.Average(s => s.m_wind_speed),
            Availability = g.Average(s => s.m_availability),
            Comments = g.Select(s => s.Comments).ToArray(),
            Countries = g.Select(i => i.Country).ToArray(),
        }
    )
    .ToListAsync()
)
.Select(g => new statisticsDaily
{
    Year = g.Year
    Date = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(g.Date),
    Production = g.Production,
    m_wind_speed = g.m_wind_speed,
    Availability = g.Availability,
    Comments = String.Join(", ", g.Comments),
    Countries = String.Join(", ", g.Countries),
})
.ToList();
```

Can you check to see what error you get now?

Comment: @mortezasol - No, you don't. You didn't copy my code correctly.

Comment: State 'IEnumerable<statisticsDaily>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no accessible extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<statisticsDaily>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have a [mcve] to work from so I didn't check compilation. Hang on a tick.

Comment: @mortezasol - Is that better?

Comment: i get the same error you can see in my question,translation ,i dont know why EFcore is so,can write query as easy.NetFramework

Comment: is it the case?https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/59892940/ef-3-1--overcome-linq-groupby-sql-translation-problem

Comment: The only other thing that I don't think can get translated is the `IPAddress.Parse(id)`. Can you try taking that out?